# How do I use executeQuery in grails testcase?

Tags: grails, testcase

How do I use executeQuery in grails testcase?

```
A error : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method ***.executeQuery() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I have already called mockDomain.

By the way, it is in unit test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no support for HQL queries in unit tests yet, but we're working on it. But you shouldn't be doing persistence tests with mocks. Persistence tests should be done against a database in an integration test.

I usually move HQL queries to the domain class as static query methods. This way they're easy to mock in a unit test of a controller, service, etc. and then I test the method as part of the domain class integration test.

For example I'd have

```
class User {
   String username
   String password
   ...

   static List findAllUsersBlahBlah(String foo, boolean bar) {
      executeQuery('from User u where ...')
   }
}
```

Then in a unit test I can mock that method with fake data since I don't care about persistence in a controller unit test - I know that it's properly tested in the correct place and I want to focus on the class under test, not its collaborators:

```
def users = [new User(...), new User(...)]
User.metaClass.static.findAllUsersBlahBlah = { String foo, boolean bar -> users }
```

Comment: I tried other solutions first but in the end has to use this one, thanks

Comment: metaclassing can cause further problems if you do not clean after using. you were warned.

Answer (score 8):

We have successfully mocked executeQuery with Grails 2.0 in our project

```
@TestFor(BookController)
@TestMixin([DomainClassUnitTestMixin,ServiceUnitTestMixin])
@ConfineMetaClassChanges([Book])
class BookControllerSpec extends Specification{
   mockDomain(Book)
   Book.metaClass.static.executeQuery = {a,b,c-> return [Book]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 2.5.4 you can use `GroovyMock` for mocking static methods implemented in Java:

```
 GroovyMock(Book, global: true)
```

I just tested - it works also for `_.executeQuery()`

Comment: Can you please provide a sample unit test which implements this.